# How do I setup files to run multiple flask (nginx, gunicorn) applications on one server? (specify separate ports)

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn, centos8

After getting each application to run on their own you need to specify the port in the application, nginx and gunicorn/service files. I am using AWS with Centos 8 operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example below is running right now on an AWS free tier machine and I can access both websites. I just changed the names to a generic "App1" and "App2".

To do this you actually only need to adjust the nginx .conf file and the .service file for gunicorn. No adjustments needed to my flask/python files. Here is the general folder structure of the files I’m referencing for 2 applications:

[image]

With this example I will run app1 on the default, which I thought was 80 but maybe its 8000, and app2 on 8001.

File setup:

App1Domain.com.conf

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  App1Domain.com;
        client_max_body_size 30M;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/environments/App1ProjectFolder/app_package/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

App2Domain.com.conf

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  App2Domain.com;
        client_max_body_size 30M;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/applications/App2ProjectFolder/app_package/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

App1.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve App1 in conda environment
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/environments/App1ProjectFolder
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/App1/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/App1/bin/gunicorn -w 3 run:app --timeout 300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

App2.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve App2 in a venv environment
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/applications/App2ProjectFolder
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/environments/App2/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/environments/App2/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8001 run:app --timeout 300

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```